# Prevent update several column in a database row

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want prevent update of two columns in a database row mysql by triggers, for ex my table is `mymy` and they two columns are `column1` and `column2` and row id is `11`. How run it in mysql triggers?

[image]

I tried it as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'no_update' BEFORE INSERT ON 'mymy' 
FOR EACH ROW BEFORE UPDATE , then check if NEW.column1 != OLD.column1 OR NEW.column2 != OLD.column2
```

and i have error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'BEFORE UPDATE , then check if NEW.id_relation != OLD.id_relation
>   OR NEW.active !' at line 1

How can fix it?

Comment: What is the query that is being run that updates both columns?

Comment: Have a try and show how far you got. In the manual there are plenty of examples.

Comment: You can create a trigger , BEFORE UPDATE , then check if NEW.column1 != OLD.column1 OR NEW.column2 != OLD.column2 , raise application error , or inform user

Comment: @TaylorGomez - You've been given an explanation on how to do it, not SQL code you can just copy and paste. The question suggests you're kind of familiar with SQL and trigger syntax.

Comment: Well, obviously your self made up syntax "then check if ..." is totally wrong. You can't just talk to a computer like you would with a human. Look up correct syntax in the manual and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to ever update the values of column1 and column2 then you can use the trigger to set the new values to the old ones, thus never updating them - I believe this to be what you're looking for.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON mymy
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.column1 = OLD.column1, NEW.column2 = OLD.column2
END
```

Comment: what is the down vote for? - Doesn't this provide an answer to your problem?